# Correct PHP headers for downloading a stored file

Tags: php, mysql

I have used this style of coding to place a file on my MYSQL database. I'm pretty certain it's stored correctly

```
if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)
{
$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

$fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);

if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
}
```

But i'm having trouble downloading it from  the database, and my headers are wrong.

```
$resumename = get_the_author_meta('resumename', $current_user->ID); 
$resumetype = get_the_author_meta('resumetype', $current_user->ID); 
$resumesize = get_the_author_meta('resumesize', $current_user->ID); 
$content = get_the_author_meta('resumecontent', $current_user->ID);

header("Content-Length: $resumesize");
header("Content-Type: $resumetype");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$resumename");

echo($content);
```

At the moment it returns a corrupt file, of the page (it's loading the actual page data using the headers, rather then the file data).

Anyone know the correct headers to use for this? i have tried @readfile, it's even worse. The file types will be doc, pdf, rtf mainly. Thanks for any help!

Comment: why don't you print out the headers you are sending for debugging? - just to see if the appropriate headers are sent. Also i think you should at least add the Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary header

Answer (score 0):

```
 header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$resumename");
 header("Content-Type: $MIME_Type"); //you can use application/pdf for PDF
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```